# Django Inheritance and Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-rest-framework

I'm having a few problems with Django inheritance... Here is the model I use:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class CommunicationChannel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Entity, related_name='communication_channels')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def _get_value(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'subvalue'):
            return self.subvalue
        else:
            return "Empty"

    value = property(_get_value)

class Email(CommunicationChannel):
    subvalue = models.EmailField("Email")

class URL(CommunicationChannel):
    subvalue = models.URLField("Email")
```

The serializer class is like this:

```
class GenericCommunicationChannelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    value = serializers.Field(source='value')
    class Meta:
        model = GenericCommunicationChannel
        fields = ('value', 'description', )
```

But when I try to access the REST API I always get the value equal to 'Empty'. Anyone knows how to fix this problem? I know I could split them and have a OneToManyField for every type of CommunicationChannel, but I would really like to have them together.

Comment: Could you maybe add a short description how you access these models and when you access the _get_value?

Comment: Ups... I had forgotten to transcribe the "value = property" bit. Basically I access the model using the REST API and the serializer returns the value as "Empty", the explicit value initialization on the serializer was because it wasn't automatically detected by django-rest-framework

Comment: Could you expand on your answer, as an answer? [It's ok to self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I'm having similar [trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28430881/1075247).